# How to fix “No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1” error in java

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

i'm getting one error how to resolve this error i.e,

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1
  at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
  at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
  at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:393)
```

I'm trying to get XML column in that column data is in format of XML

```
Session session = null;
session =  getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
Query qu = session.createSQLQuery("select xml from details 
where start_date between (select * from(select eventdate from emplyoeevent 
where event='logout' and event_id in (select session_id from session 
where session_emplyoee='"+Id+"') order by eventdate asc)
where rownum=1) and TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')");
List li =  qu.list();
```

I'm getting error in `List li =  qu.list();` line.

Comment: `-1` is `java.sql.Types.LONGVARCHAR`. The hibernate dialect for your database apparently does not have a mapping for this type (maybe it doesn't support it). Which database and which Hibernate dialect are you using?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel:i'm using oracle10g and in query i trying **id** replace of **xml** is working fine but **xml** is not wirking it throws error

Comment: But which dialect are you using (`Oracle10gDialect` or another dialect)?

Comment: yes **Oracle10gDialect**

Answer (score 0):

For my case the type was missing, so setting qu.addEntity(MyBean.class); worked, in your case String.class might work

Answer (score 0):

With me I was having trouble with an unmapped MySQL table column.

Column Type: text

Then I had to use addScalar():

```
Query query =  em. createNativeQuery(originalQuery);
((SQLQuery) ((HibernateQuery) query).getHibernateQuery())
            .addScalar("column1", new LongType())
            .addScalar("column2", new IntegerType())
            .addScalar("column3", new StringType());
List<Object[]> values = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Is your query as part of the repository? Where did you make you of addScalar? I assume this is not in your entity. Thanks