# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I would like to know how to resolve this error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:369)
```

Also I refer this Question
[How to fix “No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1” error in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054695/how-to-fix-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-1-error-in-java)

But I did not get a desired solution.

My query is:

```
     Query langQuery = null; 
     List<Object[]> langList = null;
        StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
        strQuery.append("SELECT lw.langWordId,lw.wordText,lt.translatedContent from language_word lw inner join language_translation lt on ");
        strQuery.append(" lw.langWordId=lt.langWordId where lw.isActive="+Boolean.TRUE+" ");

        langQuery = session.createSQLQuery(strQuery.toString());

        langList = langQuery.list();
```

`langList = langQuery.list();` at this line i am getting this error.

My pom.xml file have dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.ga</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I mission something?

I used **addscalar** while retrieving my list but still I got that error.

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: So, which database are you using (include the full version), and what Hibernate dialect are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql and how i check hibernate dialect ?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using, and what Hibernate dialect are you using. Please be specific and complete. The hibernate dialect should specified be in your persistence.xml or maybe somewhere in code

Comment: For mysql 5.0 and hibernate 3.0 i am curretly using.

Comment: I find it hard to believe you are using such ancient versions of both MySQL and Hibernate, but even then, those are not the Hibernate dialect.

Comment: Actually when i fired criteria query then its working fine but when i fired SQL query i got this issue. firstly i use hibernate 4 dependencies but some issue over there so now i use hibernate 3 for my code. in hibernate 4 its working fine but when i convert it into hibernate3 i got that error.

Comment: hibernate dialect :org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect. i am using

Comment: Consider trying a more recent version of the dialect (eg `MySQL5Dialect`)

Comment: Add the table definition (DDL) which you are querying

Answer (score 0):

//kindly check your Query, this error occurs when you have the syntax error in your Query

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when there is no corresponding type mapping defined for specific type in db. In your case -1 is type value for LONGVARCHAR (you can check them in java.sql.Types class). and it shows that your column type in db cannot map to field type. so you should extend  MySql dialect and following code:

```
public class CustomTypeSupportDialect extends MySqlSQLDialect
{
   public CustomTypeSupportDialect ()
   {
      super();
      this.registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "column_type_name_in_mysql");
      this.registerHibernateType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "column_type_name_in_mysql");
   }
}
```

then use this dialect as your hibernate dialect.